# Spring: Delegate to custom proxy wrapper for interface injection

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop, factory

In a very large legacy application I have interfaces and classes that do **not** implement those interfaces.

The interfaces are generated based on the class so the signatures are the same (except the interface adds another exception on top) and the names are similar (so it's easy to find the class name from the interface name).

To get an implementation of the interface we do a bunch of processing and logging calls but basically use `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` to delegate to the class. Simplified it looks like this:

```
// This will create a proxy and invoke handler that calls HelloWorld.doSomething
HelloWorldInterface i = MyProxyUtil.getInstance(HelloWorldInterface.class);
i.doSomething();

public interface HelloWorldInterface {
    public void doSomething() throws Exception;  
}

public class HelloWorld {
    public void doSomething() {
     //something
    }
}
```

Is it possible with Spring annotation processing, to generically `@Autowire` all fields of type `*Interface` and have spring use `MyProxyUtil.getInstance(*Interface.class)` to inject the implementation?

Such that

```
@Autowire HelloWorldInterface a;

HelloWorldInterface b = MyProxyUtil.getInstance(HelloWorldInterface.class);

@Autowire AnotherInterface c;

AnotherInterface d = MyProxyUtil.getInstance(AnotherInterface.class);


a == b
c == d
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement a  `AutowireCandidateResolver`.

For example:

```
public class ProxyAutowiredCandidateResolver extends SimpleAutowireCandidateResolver {

    @Override
    public Object getSuggestedValue(DependencyDescriptor descriptor) {
        String dependencyClassName = descriptor.getDependencyType().getSimpleName();
        if (dependencyClassName.endsWith("Interface")) {
            return MyProxyUtil.getInstance(descriptor.getDependencyType());
        }

        return super.getSuggestedValue(descriptor);
    }

}
```

You could use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to configure it in the application context:

```
public class AutowireCandidateResolverConfigurer implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private AutowireCandidateResolver autowireCandidateResolver;

    public void postProcessBeanFactory(
            ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        DefaultListableBeanFactory  bf = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory;
        bf.setAutowireCandidateResolver(autowireCandidateResolver);


    }

    public AutowireCandidateResolver getAutowireCandidateResolver() {
        return autowireCandidateResolver;
    }

    public void setAutowireCandidateResolver(

            AutowireCandidateResolver autowireCandidateResolver) {
        this.autowireCandidateResolver = autowireCandidateResolver;
    }

}

<bean id="autowireCandidateResolverConfigurer" class="AutowireCandidateResolverConfigurer">
        <property name="autowireCandidateResolver">
            <bean class="ProxyAutowiredCandidateResolver" />
        </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm having difficulty figuring out how you actually configure this to be used? What would I add to my applicationContext.xml?

Comment: @casenelson you can use a `BeanFactoryPostprocessor` to configure the `AutowireCandidateResolver`

Comment: There is problem with injecting Environment with your solution -> https://github.com/mariuszs/env-is-null

Comment: @MariuszS There is a problem registering directly BFPP in a Configuration class. Because the configuration class must be instantiated to create the BFPP, the bean post-processing is skipped as instantiation occurs too early, before BPPs are registered. You could use a static method to register the BFPP to avoid the problem. see  https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8269 for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, you should be able to define them in a JavaConfig `@Configuration` annotated class and then use them elsewhere.

From the docs ([Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-basic-concepts)):

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
  public MyService myService() {
      return new MyServiceImpl();
  }
}
```

You could do something similar:

```
@Configuration
public class InterfaceConfig {
  @Bean
  public HelloWorldInterface helloWorldInterface() {
      return MyProxyUtil.getInstance(HelloWorldInterface.class);
  }
}
```

At that point, Spring would use that definition whenever that bean was needed.

You'd have to link in the `@Configuration` class somehow (classpath scanning, programmatically, etc), but that depends on how you're setting up your application context.

I think this should work. I've used JavaConfig quite a bit, but never quite like this. But it seems reasonable.

Comment: It's not really practical for me to define every one of these beans in the config (there are hundreds). Rather, I'm looking for a way to resolve all interfaces whose name ends with Interface through MyProxyUtil.

Comment: I didn't catch that part.  If it IS all legacy, it wouldn't be hard to write a script to generate the code a single time.  Jose's answer sounds interesting though, I wasn't familiar with that.  Are the proxies already spring-managed?  Are you trying to do anything with them that would require for them to be spring managed if not?