# Setup Easymock with Spring @Configuration so EntityManagerFactory objects are mocked?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, easymock

I want to set up my Spring unit tests to automatically use EasyMock to mock EntityManagerFactory objects without needing to define those objects in the @Configuration.

I already figured out how to set up Spring so that it automatically uses EasyMock.createMock for any normal object that isn't defined.

```
See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687240/spring-delegate-to-custom-proxy-wrapper-for-interface-injection
```

This required creating my own SimpleAutowireCandidateResolver which calls EasyMock.createMock for any object that's not defined by the default AutowireCandidateResolver.getSuggestedValue call.

However, it turns out that EntityManagerFactory objects don't use getSuggestedValue.

If I add the following to my Spring @Configuration, it works fine:

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory someUnitNameIDefined() {return EasyMock.createMock(EntityManagerFactory.class);}
```

However, I've got lots of entity managers in different projects and I'd just like it to default to the above behavior for any EntityManager that I don't define myself in the @Configuration.

Is there something like DefaultListableBeanFactory.setAutowireCandidateResolver which would work for PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor (which appears to be the class that resolves entity managers)?